# Angular JS javascript array notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was wondering what kind of javascript object needed to be able to call notation like this `{{item.descriptions.comments}}`

The code is like this

```
<div ng-app="manyminds" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="idea item" ng-repeat="item in items" isoatom>    
    <br />
    {{item.descriptions.comments}}
</div>
</div>

angular.module('manyminds', [], function() {}).filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, min, max) {
        var range = [];
        min = parseInt(min); //Make string input int
        max = parseInt(max);
        for (var i=min; i<=max; i++)
            input[i] && range.push(input[i]);
        return range;
    };
});

    function MainCtrl($scope)
    {

        $scope.items = [
            {descriptions:[
                {
                    comments: [
                        'comment A in item 0',
                        'comment B in item 0'
                        ]
                },
                {
                    comments: [
                        'comment A in item 1',
                        'comment B in item 1',
                        'comment C in item 1',
                        'comment D in item 1'
                        ]
                }
            ]},
            {descriptions:[
                {
                    comments: [
                        'comment A in item 0',
                        'comment B in item 0'
                        ]
                },
                {
                    comments: [
                        'comment A in item 1',
                        'comment B in item 1',
                        'comment C in item 1',
                        'comment D in item 1'
                        ]
                }
            ]},     
            ];
    }
```

I can show it up if the notation is like this `{{item.descriptions}}` but how should I set up $scope.items to be able to called like this `{{item.descriptions.comments}}`

Comment: `{item:{descriptions:{comments:"Hello World!"}}}` though, that of course will only work for a single item/description/comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming items, descriptions, and comments are all supposed to be arrays, you can nest ng-repeats, if you're trying to show comments for each description:

```
<div ng-app="manyminds" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="idea item" ng-repeat="item in items" isoatom>    
    <div ng-repeat="description in item.descriptions">
       <div ng-repeat="comment in description.comments">
          {{ comment }}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `$scope.items` and try to access it via `{{item}}` which won't work.

Either use `$scope.item` or access it with {{items}} in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/r8Vnqxmwiu1D9Oi1u9D4?p=preview

which is basically nested `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

This could be the item you need:

```
$scope.items = [
  {
    name:'item1',
    descriptions: [
      {
        name:'description1',
        comments:['commentary1','commentary2']
      },
      {
        name:'description2',
        comments:['commentary1','commentary2']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name:'item2',
    descriptions: [
      {
        name:'description1',
        comments:['commentary1','commentary2']
      },
      {
        name:'description2',
        comments:['commentary1','commentary2']
      }
    ]
  }];
```

view should be something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="description in item.descriptions">
    <h3>{{description.name}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in description.comments">
      <p>{{comment}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @apaul34208 I appreciate your advice ;)